# Most effective, secure way to delete Postgres column data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a column in my Postgres table that I want to remove for expired rows. What's the best way to do this securely? It's my understanding that simply writing 0's for those columns is ineffective because Postgres creates a new row upon Updates and marks the old row as dead.

Is the best way to set the column to null and manually vacuum to clean up the old records?

Comment: you can remove column via migration

Comment: or you wanna leave it? and just remove all data?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to securely erase the column contents? What is the reason?

Comment: I want to expire rows that are older than 1 year. Instead of deleting the rows completely, I want to just delete the data in their sensitive columns. I don't want to remove the column entirely for the table because it's still in use by new records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first say that it is bad practice to alter data like this - you are changing history. Also the below is only ONE way to do this (a quick and dirty way and not to be recommended):

1 Backup your database first.
2 Open PgAdmin, select the database, open the Query Editor and run a query.
3 It would be something like this

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <column_name>=<new value (eg null)>
WHERE <record is dead>
```

The WHERE part is for you to figure out based on you are identifying which rows are dead (eg. is_removed=true, is_deleted=true are common for identifying soft deleted records).

Obviously you would have to run this script regularly. The better way would be to update your application to do this job instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the column I'm setting to null contains sensitive information (think encrypted card numbers), am I guaranteed that the Update is truly removing this data from disk?

Comment: If the data is encrypted and then removed from the database, it is going to be pretty hard for anyone to retreive it. The data will still exist on the disk itself somewhere, but over time the sector it existed on will get overwritten. There is no easy way to determine which disk sectors the database used to store that data, so I'd say you are pretty safe.